# Search a string/text in range of cells under single column

Tags: string, search, range

I wish to search a string (say name) across a list of other string under a single column. if string/name is found i want to return header name. Please advise.

Column A
Name1

Column B
List Item 1
List Item 2
List Item 3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language? What is cells, columns? What are you talking about: database table, or csv file, or what?

Comment: Have you tried anything? please post the code